TypeGraphQL-Prisma Enhancement Not Working
Describe the issue
I'm using apollo server, typegraphql-prisma, when I want to apply an authorize on a specific field with applyModelsEnhanceMap the change is as if it did not exist, I start the queries and I can still see the password
Are you able to make a PR that fix this?
import { ApolloServer, } from '@apollo/server';
import { startServerAndCreateNextHandler } from '@as-integrations/next';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

import { resolvers, ModelsEnhanceMap, applyModelsEnhanceMap, Role } from "@/../prisma/generated/type-graphql";
import { AuthChecker, Authorized, buildSchema, createMethodMiddlewareDecorator, createParameterDecorator } from "type-graphql";
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export const authChecker: AuthChecker<{ user: { role: string } }> = ({ context: { user } }, roles) => {
return false;
};

const modelsEnhanceMap: ModelsEnhanceMap = {
User: {
fields: {
password: [Authorized("ADMIN")],
},
},
};
applyModelsEnhanceMap(modelsEnhanceMap);

const schema = await buildSchema({
resolvers,
validate: false,
authChecker,
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
schema
});
const nextHandlerPromise = startServerAndCreateNextHandler(server, {
context: async () => ({ user: { id: "cm0wf7tkb0000yi5cjb7lrwrv", role: Role.USER }, prisma }),
})

const handler = async (req: NextRequest) => {
const nextHandler = await nextHandlerPromise;
return nextHandler(req);
};

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

Additional context
I tried to do the same with applyResolversEnhanceMap on the entire model and it works perfectly
